# A conditional to load different div tags for mobile / desktop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm attempting to load separate `<div>...</div>` that is conditional to whether the client is using mobile or desktop. As a simple explanation, the desktop div will contain classes sourced from a JS file, which works fine on desktop but is buggy on mobile.

Though my syntax is very layman, is there something that could emulate this conditional in HTML?

```html
<body>
  <!-- if user is using mobile -->
  <div class="mobile-div">...</div>

  <!-- if user is using desktop -->
  <div class="desktop-div js-effects">...</div>
</body>
```

Comment: html has no such conditional logic

Comment: Use `media queries` and `display: none` for the tags you want to hide.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov, good point. I'll try it out.

Comment: @irahorecka, If you have any questions or difficulties, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use media queries in css to achieve this

```
.mobile-div {
  display:none;
}
.desktop-div {
  display:block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .mobile-div {
    display:block;
  }
  .desktop-div {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have different options here, but HTML can’t do conditional.

**Option 1: Hide one of the divs on desktop or mobile with CSS `@media-queries:`**

```
.desktop-div {
  display:none;
}

@media (min-width:482px) {
  .mobile-div {
    display:none;
  }

  .desktop-div {
  display:block;
  }
}
```

Which is the more common option I would say…

**Option 2: Instruct JS to only do effects on specific window width.**

```
if (window.innerWidth > 482) {
  …
}
```

This could be the slightly more uncommon, but more performant approach, since you would load less into your DOM. In most cases I would prefer option 1

Answer (score 0):

try using `media queries` if the viewport width is less than or equal to `480px` the consider it as mobile and hide the nessary elements.

```
.mobile-div {
   display: none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .desktop-div {
       display: none;
    }
    .mobile-div {
       display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not consistent through browsers. You should either set max-width to `480.99px` or use a default and just overwrite once like I did in my example